# Swagger redirects only to HTTPS, while other endpoints work on HTTP - NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with Swagger interface on a NestJS server running on a Windows Server environment and managed by PM2. While other endpoints work on HTTP, the Swagger interface is only accessible via HTTPS. I'm accessing the server over VPN and since HTTPS is not required, I'd like to make Swagger accessible over HTTP.

I've configured the Swagger setup in the main.ts file of the NestJS application.

I'm unsure of what I need to do or where I may have gone wrong. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

I'm facing an issue with Swagger interface on a NestJS server. While it works perfectly fine when accessed via localhost, it fails to load when accessed over VPN network. Other endpoints work correctly over the VPN, only Swagger seems to have this problem.

Here is my main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import helmet from 'helmet';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  // security
  app.enableCors({
    origin: configService.get('CORS_ORIGIN'),
    credentials: true,
  });
  app.use(helmet());

  const swaggerConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Logo Api')
    .setDescription('TCS Logo Api Documentation')
    .setVersion('1.0.0')
    .addBearerAuth(
      { 
        description: `Please enter token in following format: Bearer <JWT>`,
        name: 'Authorization',
        bearerFormat: 'Bearer',
        scheme: 'Bearer',
        type: 'http',
        in: 'Header'
      },
      'access-token',
    )
    .build()
  const swaggerDocument = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, swaggerDocument);

  await app.listen(configService.get('PORT'));
}
bootstrap();
```

[And here is my browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhilM.png)